# Build release version of shared *.so library with Android Studio

Tags: c++, android-studio, c++11, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin

I am making a C++ share library for Android. I created new project with Android Studio and enabled C++.

[image]

I also enabled C++ 11 ans Exception support.

[image]

New project was created and the `build.gradle` and `CMakeLists.text` files were generated. The problem is that Adnroid Studio is only generating a Debug version of the *.so library. I need the release version to be generated too.

The debug library is being generated at

> \app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\\libnative-lib.so

I noticed there is another directory at

> \app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\

but it is empty. It does not have the release version of the library.

How can I force Android Studio to build/compile the release version of the *.so library. I put those images up to make sure that I didn't miss any step.

Using *Android Studio 2.3*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Played around with Android Studio and discovered that this can be changed by selecting the Root of your project (app) going to *Build* --> *Select Build Variant...* then change the *Build Variant* from *Debug* to *Release*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the gradle target assembleRelease in the commandline. This will automatically build for all architectures. `gradlew` should be in the root of the Android Studio project.

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```