# Android Studio C++ NDK library example

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk

I would like to download some working example of Android Studio NDK project with C or C++ which will be compiled to .so library (or APK from which I can extract .so).
I have tried ndkbuild with Android.mk build and also CMake with CMakeLists.txt, official and unofficial tutorials on Windows...

If I try them on android from same app (java), it is working but I want to use NDK in Unity3D on android and I keep getting DllNotFoundException.

I uploaded my [Android](https://github.com/spixy/AndroidNdkTest) and [Unity](https://github.com/spixy/UnityNdkTest) projects to github.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace from the exception, not just the name, as that should indicate which library is missing.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/spixy/df250fbb22f6f1c7c57de7ee0a6a60fc

Comment: Did you see the answer I left?

Comment: thank you, I saw it and downloaded the project, I wont have PC for 10 days so I will try it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [here](https://github.com/programmercert/ScreenPointPixel) is a sample Android Project plugin you are looking for.

It's very important to know how to do this yourself.

This used to be hard to do before but the latest *Android Studio* made it easier to now use C/C++ or generate **.so** library easily. Update *Android Studio* to the latest version then follow steps below to create a C++ plugin.

**1**.Create a new Project in Android Studio

**2**.Check the **Include C++ suport** to enable C++.

[image]

**3**.On the Dropdown Menu, check **C++ 11** on the *C++ Standard* drop-down menu. You will need C++ 11 to actually use most useful C++ features. Also, enable exception or frtti if you need them.

[image]

That's really it.

When you build the plugin:

The debug library is should be at:

```
\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\
```

The release library is should be at:

```
\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\
```

If you only see the debug but not the release version of the plugin, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43880214/3785314) for how to make it appear.

---

Possible reasons you are getting *DllNotFoundException* on Android:

**1**.You did not wrap the C/C++ function around `extern "C"`. You must do this for each function in the *.cpp* file or you do it in the function in the *.h* file.

**2**.You put the plugin in the wrong Unity folder.

The armeabi-v7a and x86  plugins generated at `<ProjectDirectory>\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj` should be placed at `Assets\Plugins\Android\libs\armeabi-v7a\` and `Assets\Plugins\Android\libs\x86\` in the Unity project.

Make sure to spell these correctly. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44028008/3785314) for more information about this.

**3**.You are loading it incorrectly from the C# side.

Let's say that the name of the plugin is libScreenshot.a, do **not** include the lib prefix, also do **not** add the `.a` when loading it.

```
[DllImport("Screenshot", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void takeScreenshot();
```

Comment: Thank you, 
at first I used obj from `\app\build\outputs\...` and my Unity folder was named *lib*, not *libs* but then it still did not work.
now it works