# Error while integrating openCV 3.2.0 with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, android-ndk

I get this error while integrating openCV with android studio.

I am new to android and not able to understand why this error occurs.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
>   Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
>   Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration with the stable Android Gradle plugin:
>    https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html
>   or use the experimental plugin:
>    https://developer.android.com/studio/build/experimental-plugin.html.

Comment: i got this error while integrating opencv with android studio. i am new to android and not able to understand this error

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you should try one of the NDK examples provided by Google, and become familiar with using the NDK before trying a large library like OpenCV on Android Studio. The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509848/android-studio-c-ndk-library-example) are quite detailed, and can be helpful.